# What multi-map-like data structure can support replacement while maintaining order?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, guava, boost-multi-index

I'm looking to implement a multi-map that maintains insertion order of the entries, and allows in-place insertion/replacement without affecting the order.  Guava's `LinkedListMultimap` is almost perfect, but doesn't allow the type of replacement I'm looking for.  `LinkedListMultimap` is implemented as a hash map and multiple linked lists; it looks like this:

```
                             ________________
                            /                \
(A,1) -> (B,2) -> (A,3) -> (C,4) -> (B,5) -> (C,6) -> (A,7)
 \________\_______/\________________/_________________/
           \_______________________/
```

Internally, every node has a pointer to the next node in the sequence, as well as the next node with the same key, and a hash table maintains a mapping from keys to the first node with that key.

Unfortunately, this doesn't allow for efficient in-place insertions or replacements.  For example, to replace `(C,4)` with `(B,8)`, I'd have to walk backwards an arbitrarily long way to find `(B,2)` in order to update its "next of same key" pointer.

The best idea I have to far is to associate each element with a sequence number, and keep a sorted set for each key.  But to insert in the middle of the sequence, I would need infinitely divisible sequence numbers.

(By the way, I'm implementing this in C++, but I'm just looking for a description of a data structure that would work.  If there's a pre-existing library that would work that would be great, but even `boost::multi_index_container` doesn't seem up to the task.)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer #1**

Why is Boost.MultiIndex not helping you here?

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b690a72d6f05ba44)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

#include <iosfwd>

template<typename T,typename Q>
struct pair_
{
  T first;
  Q second;
};

template<typename T,typename Q>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const pair_<T,Q>& p)
{
  return os<<"("<<p.first<<","<<p.second<<")";
}

template<typename T,typename Q>
using list_multimap=multi_index_container<
  pair_<T,Q>,
  indexed_by<
    sequenced<>,
    ordered_non_unique<
      composite_key<
        pair_<T,Q>,
        member<pair_<T,Q>,T,&pair_<T,Q>::first>,
        member<pair_<T,Q>,Q,&pair_<T,Q>::second>
      >
    >
  >
>;

template<typename T,typename Q>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const list_multimap<T,Q>& lmm)
{
   for(const auto& p:lmm)os<<p<<" ";
   return os;
}

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  list_multimap<std::string,int> lmm{{"A",1},{"B",2},{"A",3},{"C",4},{"B",5},{"C",6},{"A",7}};
  auto&                          mm=lmm.get<1>();

  std::cout<<lmm<<"\n";

  // List values with key "A"

  auto r=mm.equal_range("A");
  while(r.first!=r.second)std::cout<<*(r.first)++<<" ";
  std::cout<<"\n";

  // replace (C,4) with (B,8)

  mm.replace(mm.find(std::make_tuple("C",4)),{"B",8});
  std::cout<<lmm<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Look at `mm.equal_range("B")` afterwards; it's `(B,2) (B,5) (B,8)` instead of `(B,2) (B,8) (B,5)`.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/076cc158114c4b6a

Comment: I understand. See my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer #2**

My first answer can be refined to get what you're after, I think:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/430817dd9f7c9b3f)</kbd>**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <functional>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

#include <iosfwd>

template<typename T,typename Q>
struct pair_
{
  T first;
  Q second;

  using compare=std::function<bool(const pair_&,const pair_&)>;
  mutable compare* subcmp;

  pair_(const T& first,const Q& second,compare* subcmp=nullptr):
    first(first),second(second),subcmp(subcmp){}
};

namespace std{

template<typename T,typename Q>
struct less<pair_<T,Q>>
{
  bool operator()(const pair_<T,Q>& x,const pair_<T,Q>& y)const
  {
     if(x.first<y.first)return true;
     if(y.first<x.first)return false;
     if(x.subcmp)       return (*x.subcmp)(x,y);
     if(y.subcmp)       return (*y.subcmp)(x,y);
     return false;
  }

  template<typename R>
  bool operator()(const R& x,const pair_<T,Q>& y)const
  {
     return x<y.first;
  }

  template<typename R>
  bool operator()(const pair_<T,Q>& x,const R& y)const
  {
     return x.first<y;
  }
};

} // namespace std

template<typename T,typename Q>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const pair_<T,Q>& p)
{
  return os<<"("<<p.first<<","<<p.second<<")";
}

template<typename T,typename Q>
using list_multimap=multi_index_container<
  pair_<T,Q>,
  indexed_by<
    random_access<>,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<pair_<T,Q>>>
  >
>;

template<typename T,typename Q>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const list_multimap<T,Q>& lmm)
{
   for(const auto& p:lmm)os<<p<<" ";
   return os;
}

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  list_multimap<std::string,int> lmm{{"A",1},{"B",2},{"A",3},{"C",4},{"B",5},{"C",6},{"A",7}};
  auto&                          mm=lmm.get<1>();

  std::cout<<lmm<<"\n";

  // list values with key "A"

  auto r=mm.equal_range("A");
  while(r.first!=r.second)std::cout<<*(r.first)++<<" ";
  std::cout<<"\n";

  // replace (C,4) with (B,8)

  pair_<std::string,int>::compare subcmp=[&](const auto&x, const auto& y){
    auto itx=lmm.iterator_to(x);
    auto ity=lmm.iterator_to(y);
    return itx<ity;
  };

  r=mm.equal_range("C");
  auto it=std::find_if(r.first,r.second,[](const auto& x){return x.second==4;});
  mm.modify(it,[&](auto&x){x={"B",8,&subcmp};});
  it->subcmp=nullptr;
  std::cout<<lmm<<"\n";

  // list values with key "B"

  r=mm.equal_range("B");
  while(r.first!=r.second)std::cout<<*(r.first)++<<" ";
  std::cout<<"\n";  
}
```

The key ideas are:

- Use a random-access index instead of a sequenced one.
- Let elements be subsorted (when the keys are equal) by a user-provided comparison function, stored in `subcmp`, which is optional (if `subcmp` is null).
- When replacing values, use `modify` (so as to change the element in place) and provide a subcomparer that simply respects the order of the elements in the random-access index. After modification is done, set `subcmp` to `nullptr` as it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer #3**

My second answer can be further refined to place the subcomparer within the `less<pair_<T,Q>>` object itself:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d06ca711a2d0f01f)</kbd>**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <functional>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

#include <iosfwd>

template<typename T,typename Q>
struct pair_
{
  T first;
  Q second;
};

namespace std{

template<typename T,typename Q>
struct less<pair_<T,Q>>
{
  using subcompare=std::function<bool(const pair_<T,Q>&,const pair_<T,Q>&)>;
  subcompare subcmp;

  bool operator()(const pair_<T,Q>& x,const pair_<T,Q>& y)const
  {
     if(x.first<y.first)return true;
     if(y.first<x.first)return false;
     if(subcmp)         return subcmp(x,y);
     return false;
  }

  template<typename R>
  bool operator()(const R& x,const pair_<T,Q>& y)const
  {
     return x<y.first;
  }

  template<typename R>
  bool operator()(const pair_<T,Q>& x,const R& y)const
  {
     return x.first<y;
  }
};

} // namespace std

template<typename T,typename Q>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const pair_<T,Q>& p)
{
  return os<<"("<<p.first<<","<<p.second<<")";
}

template<typename T,typename Q>
using list_multimap=multi_index_container<
  pair_<T,Q>,
  indexed_by<
    random_access<>,
    ordered_non_unique<
      identity<pair_<T,Q>>,
      std::reference_wrapper<const std::less<pair_<T,Q>>>>
  >
>;

template<typename T,typename Q>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const list_multimap<T,Q>& lmm)
{
   for(const auto& p:lmm)os<<p<<" ";
   return os;
}

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::less<pair_<std::string,int>> less;
  list_multimap<std::string,int>    lmm{boost::make_tuple(
                                      boost::make_tuple(),
                                      boost::make_tuple(
                                        identity<pair_<std::string,int>>{},
                                        std::cref(less)
                                      )
                                    )};
  auto&                             mm=lmm.get<1>();

  lmm={{"A",1},{"B",2},{"A",3},{"C",4},{"B",5},{"C",6},{"A",7}};
  std::cout<<lmm<<"\n";

  // list values with key "A"

  auto r=mm.equal_range("A");
  std::for_each(r.first,r.second,[](const auto& x){std::cout<<x<<" ";});
  std::cout<<"\n";

  // replace (C,4) with (B,8)

  std::less<pair_<std::string,int>>::subcompare subcmp=
  [&](const auto&x, const auto& y){
    return lmm.iterator_to(x)<lmm.iterator_to(y);
  };

  r=mm.equal_range("C");
  auto it=std::find_if(r.first,r.second,[](const auto& x){return x.second==4;});
  less.subcmp=subcmp;
  mm.modify(it,[](auto& x){x={"B",8};});
  less.subcmp=nullptr;
  std::cout<<lmm<<"\n";

  // list values with key "B"

  r=mm.equal_range("B");
  std::for_each(r.first,r.second,[](const auto& x){std::cout<<x<<" ";});
  std::cout<<"\n";  
}
```

This gets us an important reduction in memory usage, as the elements themselves need not come with an additional pointer for `subcmp`. The general strategy remains exactly the same.

Comment: I see what you've done, very nice!  Sadly insertion into the middle of a `random_access` index is `O(n)`, but since it doesn't involve copies it's probably fast in practice for my case.  I am curious if it can be done in sublinear time though.

Comment: (Off Boost.MultiIndex realm.) To do sublinear replacement you need to know, given two elements `x` and `y`, which comes first in the sequence. A vector-like sequence gives you that in constant time but, as you point out, mid insertion is O(n). An alternative would be to use an order statistics tree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) as your base sequence: relative ordering check can be done in O(log n), as well as mid insertion.

Comment: Ah an order statistic tree is perfect!  Can't believe I didn't think of it myself actually.  If you put that as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: You will have to measure, but I bet the vector-like sequence as sported in my example with Boost.MultiIndex will beat the order statistic tree in practice. Please let me know if you do the exercise.